# LibreSSL provide authentication tag for aes-256-gcm

Tags: openssl, aes-gcm, libressl

I'm currently running my command as so:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libressl/3.0.2/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -d -in enc.token -out dec.token -iv {IV} -K {KEY}
```

and the output of that command is `bad decrypt`. My output file also looks like it's only half decrypted, with the file looking like

`Object(id=998fdsa981sdafkj@ÛP²•v’@v[ðt`

1. Is that fully decrypted? I believe those symbols represent binary, but it looks like only half of my object got decrypted
2. I've been looking up `bad decrypt` and it seems like it has to do with the GCM encryption authentication tag not being supplied to decrypt. Is there a way to supply this to the Libre command? I've been looking through LibreSSL via https://www.libressl.org/ but there seems to be no documentation of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that LibreSSL is the same as OpenSSL in this regards. OpenSSL documents this issue on its man page for the `enc` utility:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html

> The enc program does not support authenticated encryption modes like
>   CCM and GCM, and will not support such modes in the future.

The same paragraph goes on to explain the reasoning behind this. It recommends to use the `cms` utility instead of `enc`.

Comment: If LibreSSL didn't support GCM, why would it have ```aes-256-gcm``` as a command line option?

Comment: For the same reason that OpenSSL does. It supports GCM internally - just not in conjunction with the enc app. It uses generic handling for multiple commands to parse those options and will accept *any* cipher name. It just doesn't *work* with some of them. OpenSSL detects this and spits out an error - but older versions did not and failed in the same way as you are seeing. Caveat: I don't use Libressl, only OpenSSL. I just know that OpenSSL works this way.